# Game won't start in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Im new at Programming so I followed steps in a Tutorial on Youtube for classic RPG game by using Unity and Windows Visual studio , but the Game won't start although I already assign the script to the player but he still doesn't move.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    private bool isMoving;
    private Vector2 input;

    private void Ubdate()
    {
        if (!isMoving)
        {
            input.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            input.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            if (input != Vector2.zero)
            {
                var targetPos = transform.position;
                targetPos.x += input.x;
                targetPos.y += input.y;

                StartCoroutine(Move(targetPos));
            }
        }
    }
    
    IEnumerator Move(Vector3 targetPos)
    {
        isMoving = true;
        while ((targetPos - transform.position).sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
        transform.position = targetPos;

        isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Your `Update` method has a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo so the method would never be called.

```
private void Ubdate()
```

should be

```
private void Update()
```

Beyond that typo though, the coroutine would likely also never start since the default value of bool data types in C# is false, so by default isMoving would be false and would seemingly never change.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign an Event System to the hierarchy: right click on the hierarchy, UI, Event System